# High CPU usage with Team Speak 3.0.0-rc2

Tags: 10.04, pulseaudio, alsa, cpu-load

The CPU usage is always  around 40 percent. I use push-to-talk and I had [uninstalled pulseaudio](http://www.jeffsplace.net/node/12). Now I use Alsa. I don't even have to connect to a Server. By simply starting TS the cpu usage goes up 40 percent and stays there.

The CPU usage of 3.0.0-rc1 [Build: 14468] is constantly 14 percent.

This is the output of `top`, `mpstat` and `ps aux` while I am running TS3 ... of course:

```
alexandros@alexandros-laptop:~$ top

top - 18:20:07 up  2:22,  3 users,  load average: 1.02, 0.85, 0.77
Tasks: 163 total,   1 running, 162 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  5.3%us,  1.9%sy,  0.1%ni, 91.8%id,  0.7%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2061344k total,   964028k used,  1097316k free,    69116k buffers
Swap:  3997688k total,        0k used,  3997688k free,   449032k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                  
 2714 alexandr  20   0  206m  31m  24m S   37  1.6   0:12.78 ts3client_linux                                                                          
  868 root      20   0 47564  27m  10m S    8  1.4   3:21.73 Xorg                                                                                     
    1 root      20   0  2804 1660 1204 S    0  0.1   0:00.53 init                                                                                     
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                 
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/0                                                                              
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.45 ksoftirqd/0                                                                              
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0                                                                               
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1                                                                              
    7 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.08 ksoftirqd/1                                                                              
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1                                                                               
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.17 events/0                                                                                 
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.81 events/1                                                                                 
   11 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset                                                                                   
   12 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper                                                                                  
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 async/mgr                                                                                
   14 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 pm                                                                                       
   16 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 sync_supers                                                                              
   17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 bdi-default                                                                              
   18 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd/0                                                                            
   19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd/1                                                                            
   20 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.05 kblockd/0                                                                                
   21 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.02 kblockd/1                                                                                
   22 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpid                                                                                   
   23 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpi_notify                                                                             
   24 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpi_hotplug                                                                            
   25 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.99 ata/0                                                                                    
   26 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.92 ata/1                                                                                    
   27 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_aux                                                                                  
   28 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ksuspend_usbd                                                                            
   29 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd                                                                                    
alexandros@alexandros-laptop:~$ mpstat 
Linux 2.6.32-32-generic (alexandros-laptop)     16.06.2011  _i686_  (2 CPU)

18:20:15     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
18:20:15     all    5,36    0,09    1,91    0,68    0,07    0,06    0,00    0,00   91,83
alexandros@alexandros-laptop:~$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   2804  1660 ?        Ss   15:58   0:00 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [migration/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [migration/1]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:01 [events/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [events/1]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [cpuset]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [khelper]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [async/mgr]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [pm]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [sync_supers]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [bdi-default]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kintegrityd/0]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kintegrityd/1]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kblockd/0]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kblockd/1]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kacpid]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kacpi_notify]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kacpi_hotplug]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [ata/0]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [ata/1]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [ata_aux]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [ksuspend_usbd]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [khubd]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kseriod]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kmmcd]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   15:58   0:00 [ksmd]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [aio/0]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [aio/1]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [crypto/0]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [crypto/1]
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:03 [scsi_eh_0]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kstriped]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kmpathd/0]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kmpathd/1]
root        56  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kmpath_handlerd]
root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [ksnapd]
root        58  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:03 [kondemand/0]
root        59  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:02 [kondemand/1]
root        60  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kconservative/0]
root        61  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kconservative/1]
root       213  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       222  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [scsi_eh_3]
root       234  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [scsi_eh_4]
root       235  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:01 [usb-storage]
root       255  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [jbd2/sda5-8]
root       256  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       257  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       290  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [flush-8:0]
root       318  0.0  0.0   2316   888 ?        S    15:58   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       321  0.0  0.0   2616  1024 ?        S<s  15:58   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       526  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       528  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [led_workqueue]
root       650  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [radeon/0]
root       651  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [radeon/1]
root       652  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [ttm_swap]
root       654  0.0  0.0   2612   984 ?        S<   15:58   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       656  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:00 [hd-audio0]
root       657  0.0  0.0   2612   916 ?        S<   15:58   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       674  0.6  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:58   0:57 [phy0]
syslog     715  0.0  0.0  34812  1776 ?        Sl   15:58   0:00 rsyslogd -c4
102        731  0.0  0.0   3236  1512 ?        Ss   15:58   0:02 dbus-daemon --system --fork
root       740  0.0  0.1  19088  3380 ?        Ssl  15:58   0:00 gdm-binary
root       744  0.0  0.1  18900  4032 ?        Ssl  15:58   0:01 NetworkManager
avahi      749  0.0  0.0   2928  1520 ?        S    15:58   0:00 avahi-daemon: running [alexandros-laptop.local]
avahi      752  0.0  0.0   2928   544 ?        Ss   15:58   0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
root       753  0.0  0.1   4172  2300 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/modem-manager
root       762  0.0  0.1  20584  3152 ?        Sl   15:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
root       836  0.0  0.1  20856  3864 ?        Sl   15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-simple-slave --display-id /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Display1
root       856  0.0  0.1   4836  2388 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s
root       868  2.3  1.3  36932 27924 tty7     Rs+  15:58   3:22 /usr/bin/X :0 -nr -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-a46T4j/database -nolisten
root       891  0.0  0.0   1792   564 tty4     Ss+  15:58   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       901  0.0  0.0   1792   564 tty5     Ss+  15:58   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root       908  0.0  0.0   1792   564 tty2     Ss+  15:58   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root       910  0.0  0.0   1792   568 tty3     Ss+  15:58   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root       913  0.0  0.0   1792   564 tty6     Ss+  15:58   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
root       917  0.0  0.0   2180  1072 ?        Ss   15:58   0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
daemon     924  0.0  0.0   2248   432 ?        Ss   15:58   0:00 atd
root       927  0.0  0.0   2376   900 ?        Ss   15:58   0:00 cron
root       950  0.0  0.0  11736  1372 ?        Ss   15:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/winbindd
root       958  0.0  0.0  11736  1184 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/winbindd
root       974  0.0  0.1   6832  2580 ?        Ss   15:58   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -C /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
root      1078  0.0  0.0   1792   564 tty1     Ss+  15:58   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
gdm       1097  0.0  0.0   3392   772 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session
root      1112  0.0  0.1  19216  3292 ?        Sl   15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-session-worker
root      1116  0.0  0.1   5540  2932 ?        S    15:58   0:01 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
root      1131  0.0  0.1   6308  3824 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd
108       1163  0.0  0.2  16788  4360 ?        Ssl  15:58   0:01 /usr/sbin/hald
root      1164  0.0  0.0   3536  1300 ?        S    15:58   0:00 hald-runner
root      1188  0.0  0.0   3612  1256 ?        S    15:58   0:00 hald-addon-input: Listening on /dev/input/event6 /dev/input/event5 /dev/input/event2 
root      1194  0.0  0.0   3612  1224 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/hal/hald-addon-rfkill-killswitch
root      1200  0.0  0.0   3608  1240 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/hal/hald-addon-generic-backlight
root      1202  0.0  0.0   3616  1236 ?        S    15:58   0:02 hald-addon-storage: polling /dev/sr0 (every 2 sec)
root      1204  0.0  0.0   3616  1236 ?        S    15:58   0:00 hald-addon-storage: polling /dev/sdb (every 2 sec)
root      1211  0.0  0.0   3624  1220 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/hal/hald-addon-cpufreq
108       1212  0.0  0.0   3420  1200 ?        S    15:58   0:00 hald-addon-acpi: listening on acpid socket /var/run/acpid.socket
1000      1222  0.0  0.1  24196  2816 ?        Sl   15:58   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
1000      1240  0.0  0.3  28228  7312 ?        Ssl  15:58   0:00 gnome-session
1000      1274  0.0  0.0   3284   356 ?        Ss   15:58   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session
1000      1277  0.0  0.0   3392   772 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session
1000      1278  0.0  0.0   3160  1652 ?        Ss   15:58   0:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
1000      1281  0.0  0.2   8172  4636 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/libgconf2-4/gconfd-2
1000      1287  0.0  0.5  24228 10896 ?        Ss   15:58   0:03 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
1000      1290  0.0  0.1   6468  2364 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
1000      1293  0.0  0.6  38104 13004 ?        S    15:58   0:03 metacity
1000      1296  0.0  0.1  30280  2628 ?        Ssl  15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/alexandros/.gvfs
1000      1301  0.0  0.0   3344   988 ?        S    15:58   0:03 syndaemon -i 0.5 -k
1000      1303  0.0  0.1   8060  3488 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor
root      1306  0.0  0.1  15692  3104 ?        Sl   15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/udisks/udisks-daemon
1000      1307  0.4  1.0  50748 21684 ?        S    15:58   0:34 python -u /usr/share/screenlets/DigiClock/DigiClockScreenlet.py
1000      1308  0.0  0.9  35608 18564 ?        S    15:58   0:00 python /usr/share/screenlets-manager/screenlets-daemon.py
1000      1309  0.0  0.3  19524  6468 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
1000      1311  0.0  0.5  37412 11788 ?        S    15:58   0:01 gnome-power-manager
1000      1312  0.0  1.0  50772 22628 ?        S    15:58   0:03 gnome-panel
1000      1313  0.1  1.5 102648 31184 ?        Sl   15:58   0:10 nautilus
root      1314  0.0  0.0   5188   996 ?        S    15:58   0:02 udisks-daemon: polling /dev/sdb /dev/sr0
1000      1315  0.0  0.6  51948 12464 ?        SL   15:58   0:01 nm-applet --sm-disable
1000      1317  0.0  0.1  16956  2364 ?        Sl   15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
1000      1318  0.0  0.3  20164  7792 ?        S    15:58   0:00 bluetooth-applet
1000      1321  0.0  0.1   7260  2384 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
1000      1323  0.0  0.5  37436 12124 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
1000      1324  0.0  1.9 197928 40456 ?        Ssl  15:58   0:06 /home/alexandros/.dropbox-dist/dropbox
1000      1329  0.0  0.3  20136  7968 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver --no-daemon
1000      1331  0.0  0.1   7056  3112 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.6 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
root      1340  0.0  0.0   2236  1008 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action -pf /var/run/dhcl
1000      1348  0.0  0.1  42252  3680 ?        Ssl  15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/bonobo-activation/bonobo-activation-server --ac-activate --ior-output-fd=19
1000      1384  0.0  1.7  80244 35480 ?        Sl   15:58   0:02 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/deskbar-applet/deskbar-applet/deskbar-applet --oaf-activate-
1000      1388  0.0  0.5  26196 11804 ?        S    15:58   0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-panel/wnck-applet --oaf-activate-iid=OAFIID:GNOME_Wncklet_Factory --oa
1000      1393  0.1  0.5  25876 11548 ?        S    15:58   0:08 /usr/lib/gnome-applets/multiload-applet-2 --oaf-activate-iid=OAFIID:GNOME_MultiLoadAp
1000      1394  0.0  0.5  25600 11140 ?        S    15:58   0:03 /usr/lib/gnome-applets/cpufreq-applet --oaf-activate-iid=OAFIID:GNOME_CPUFreqApplet_F
1000      1415  0.0  0.5  39192 11156 ?        S    15:58   0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-power-manager/gnome-inhibit-applet --oaf-activate-iid=OAFIID:GNOME_Inh
1000      1417  0.0  0.7  53544 15488 ?        Sl   15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-applets/mixer_applet2 --oaf-activate-iid=OAFIID:GNOME_MixerApplet_Fact
1000      1419  0.0  0.4  23816  9068 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-panel/notification-area-applet --oaf-activate-iid=OAFIID:GNOME_Notific
1000      1488  0.0  0.3  20964  7548 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-disk-utility/gdu-notification-daemon
1000      1490  0.0  0.1   6608  2484 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-burn --spawner :1.6 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/1
1000      1510  0.0  0.1   6348  2084 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
1000      1531  0.0  0.3  19472  6616 ?        S    15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-user-share/gnome-user-share
1000      1535  0.0  0.4  77128  8392 ?        Sl   15:58   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-data-server-2.28 --oaf-activate-iid=OAFIID:GNOME_Evoluti
1000      1601  0.0  0.5  69576 11800 ?        Sl   15:59   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/2.28/evolution-alarm-notify
1000      1604  0.0  0.7  33924 15888 ?        S    15:59   0:00 python /usr/share/system-config-printer/applet.py
1000      1701  0.0  0.5  37116 11968 ?        S    15:59   0:00 update-notifier
1000      1892  4.5  7.0 406720 145312 ?       Sl   17:11   3:09 /opt/google/chrome/chrome       
1000      1896  0.0  0.1  69812  3680 ?        S    17:11   0:02 /opt/google/chrome/chrome       
1000      1898  0.0  0.6  91420 14080 ?        S    17:11   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote
1000      1916  0.2  1.3 140780 27220 ?        Sl   17:11   0:12 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=extension --disable-client-side-phishing-detection -
1000      1918  0.7  1.8 155720 37912 ?        Sl   17:11   0:31 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=extension --disable-client-side-phishing-detection -
1000      1921  0.0  1.0 135904 21052 ?        Sl   17:11   0:02 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=extension --disable-client-side-phishing-detection -
1000      1927  6.5  3.6 194604 74960 ?        Sl   17:11   4:32 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --
1000      2156  0.4  0.7  48344 14896 ?        Rl   18:03   0:04 gnome-terminal
1000      2157  0.0  0.0   1988   712 ?        S    18:03   0:00 gnome-pty-helper
1000      2158  0.0  0.1   6504  3860 pts/0    Ss   18:03   0:00 bash
1000      2564  0.2  0.1   6624  3984 pts/1    Ss+  18:17   0:00 bash
1000      2711  0.0  0.0   4208  1352 ?        S    18:19   0:00 /bin/bash /home/alexandros/Programme/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86_back/ts3client_runsc
1000      2714 36.5  1.5 210872 31960 ?        SLl  18:19   0:18 ./ts3client_linux_x86
1000      2743  0.0  0.0   2716  1068 pts/0    R+   18:20   0:00 ps aux
```

Output of `vmstat`:

```
alexandros@alexandros-laptop:~$ vmstat 
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0      0 1093324  69840 449496    0    0    27    10  476  667  6  2 91  1
```

Output of `lsusb`

```
alexandros@alexandros-laptop:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 671MX
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:02.0 ISA bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS968 [MuTIOL Media IO] (rev 01)
00:02.5 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 5513 [IDE] (rev 01)
00:03.0 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.1 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.3 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 2.0 Controller
00:05.0 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SATA Controller / IDE mode (rev 03)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:0d.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
00:0f.0 Audio device: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Azalia Audio Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Mobility Radeon X2300
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5001 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

The Team Speak log file :

```
2011-06-19 19:04:04.223522|INFO    |              |   | Logging started, clientlib version: 3.0.0-rc2 [Build: 14642]
2011-06-19 19:04:04.761149|ERROR   |SoundBckndIntf|   | /home/alexandros/Programme/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86_back/soundbackends/libpulseaudio_linux_x86.so error: NOT_CONNECTED
2011-06-19 19:04:05.871770|INFO    |ClientUI      |   | Failed to init text to speech engine
2011-06-19 19:04:05.894623|INFO    |ClientUI      |   | TeamSpeak 3 client version: 3.0.0-rc2 [Build: 14642]
2011-06-19 19:04:05.895421|INFO    |ClientUI      |   | Qt version: 4.7.2
2011-06-19 19:04:05.895571|INFO    |ClientUI      |   | Using configuration location: /home/alexandros/.ts3client/ts3clientui_qt.conf
2011-06-19 19:04:06.559596|INFO    |ClientUI      |   | Last update check was: Sa. Jun 18 00:08:43 2011
2011-06-19 19:04:06.560506|INFO    |              |   | Checking for updates...
2011-06-19 19:04:07.357869|INFO    |              |   | Update check, my version: 14642, latest version: 14642
2011-06-19 19:05:52.978481|INFO    |PreProSpeex   |  1| Speex version: 1.2rc1
2011-06-19 19:05:54.055347|INFO    |UIHelpers     |   | setClientVolumeModifier: 10 -8
2011-06-19 19:05:54.057196|INFO    |UIHelpers     |   | setClientVolumeModifier: 11 2
```

Thanks for taking the time to read my message.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [nickguletskii](https://askubuntu.com/users/15898/nickguletskii)'s link I googled for "alsa cpu usage" (without quotes) and it [brought me to a forum](http://www.musicpd.org/forum/index.php?topic=1445.msg7080#msg7080). A user wrote that by directly selecting the hardware with "plughw:x.x" won't impact the performance of the system. I have selected it in the TS 3 configuration and it worked.

But this solution is not optimal because now no other program can access the sound output.

**UPDATE #2**
I followed [nickguletskii](https://askubuntu.com/users/15898/nickguletskii)'s solution and created a .asoundrc file in my home folder. Now things are getting even worse, the CPU usage is now at 50% :-O.

contents of my ~./asoundrc

```
alexandros@alexandros-laptop:~$ cat /home/alexandros/.asoundrc 
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    slave {
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        rate 44100
    }
    }
}
```

I checked that I access the correct device from my TS3 configuration. When I directly select the device the cpu usage is at 2%. When I select "Standart" it goes now up to 50%.

[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE #3**

I switched the rate down to 22050 but still no difference to 44100. CPU usage is at 50%.

**If you need any further information or my question is unclear than please tell me.**

Comment: Can you give mpstat command ouput while this program is running?

Comment: It is strange. mpstat shows that your machine is around 93% idle, that means only 7% of CPU resources are being used, which is unlike 40% TOP command output. BTW, how many cores you have?

Comment: I have an Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T2330 with 2 cores.

Comment: I posted the output of top, ps and mpstat. As you can see ps and top show the same results.

Comment: I think that you should not worry about this as mpstat shows that only 7% of your machine CPU resources are being utilized when this program is running. To make sure that try vmstat command and see what it showing.

Comment: One more thing is that try running "mpstat 1" for 10 seconds and see the change in the CPU resource usage. Some applications need high CPU resources in their first few seconds of execution (i.e. initialization period).

Comment: Thanks for your time kkp. The cpu usage is around 40% all the time. I have TS running for at least 8-10 hours a day. My normally quiet Laptop gets very loud after 20 Minutes or so.

Comment: I don't even have to connect to a TS-Server. By simply starting TS the cpu usage goes up 40% and stays there

Comment: It is really interesting problem to work on. :-)

Comment: Check your sampling rate, because this issue seems to be the same as here:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1520996

Comment: That's it! Googling for "alsa cpu usage" (without quotes) brought me to a forum. They wrote that you can bypass dmix by directly selecting the hardware with "plughw:x.x". I have selected it in the TS 3 configuration and it worked. You rock. Here is the link:  musicpd.org/forum/index.php?topic=1445.msg7080#msg7080

Comment: But now I got the problem that I no other application can use the sound output. :-( I'll update the question.

Comment: @AlexTheBird I think that what dmix does is it mixes the sound from all applications into one, which it directs to hardware. By directing output straight to hardware, you are disabling the mixer and you can only hear one application at once. Try editing ~/.asoundrc and changing "rate 48000" to something lower. 44100 as suggested here: http://www.unnaki.com/2011/04/linux-high-cpu-usage-while-playing-music/

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a resampling problem. After some googling, I found out that the [default sample rate for TeamSpeak 3.0 is 44100 Hz](http://www.eve-search.com/thread/1448107), while the default sample rate for ALSA is 48000.

Now, we need to fix that by opening `~/.asoundrc` (a hidden file called .asoundrc in your home directory) and changing `rate 48000` to `rate 44100`. This will hopefully stop the resampling and result in less CPU usage.

**EDIT:** As changing the sample rate made the issue worse, then it might be a sign that we are digging in the right direction. We need to pick the right sample rate. The fact that it happens before sounds start is what confuses me though...

Comment: I thank you so much for you time Nick, but after creating the file the CPU usage goes up to 50%. I updated the question.

Comment: @AlexTheBird So that is good news: we know that the problem is with sampling rates. Now, we need to find out which one we need.

Comment: @AlexTheBird Try setting it to 22050, the sound files that come with TeamSpeak use that sampling rate.

Comment: I've had this with Ekiga - ended up switching to Twinkle. Can you use another product instead of TeamSpeak, say, Mumble?

Comment: @nickguletskii I am sorry for the late response, I got a lot of work atm. I have tried setting it to 22050 in .asoundrc but it didn't made any change.

Comment: @Broam I am thinking about switching to something else. But that is not so easy because I seem to be the only one having those problems.